# For careers relocation, how to specify "anywhere"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

If you aren't bothered about where to relocate to, how does one specify "anywhere" as a relocation option?

Just leaving the location options blank doesn't allow you to distinguish between the areas that you'd like to go and the areas that you are currently legally entitled to work in.

If it isn't already an available feature, I suggest adding "Anywhere" as a location keyword.

Comment: Are you willing to relocation to Iran etc, if not you are not willing to go anywhere...

Comment: For the right challenge/salary I think "anywhere" is still valid.  And it's probably easier to list exemptions than to think of all the places I might want to go, and find the appropriate keywords that the system accepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion! We deliberately do not allow "anywhere" as it will significantly increase the amount of noise in the system.

There's no way to determine whether someone that has their relocation preference set to anywhere has the legal right to work at any given location, and most locations would probably only be considered for that one in a million job. But in the mean time, this person will show up in significantly more searches. Most of the additional people the employers would find would probably not be interested in working for them (or the employer wouldn't be willing to relocate them), and most of the additional messages candidates would get would be for positions/places they would not consider. But to determine this the extra profiles need to be scanned and the extra messages read and responded to.

The added noise would end up diminishing the overall quality of the search results and messages, which would not be a good thing.

Comment: So for someone who is open to working "anywhere".  What do we do?  Should we leave it blank? (what effect will that have?) Or should we list many countries? What would be the effect if I didn't list a specific country, versus having left the field blank?  I think the logic in this answer is sound; but it would be helpful to specify to users how this field works, what its effect are - so we can make an informed choice for what to do.