# Can I filter jobs on Careers by continent?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am looking for a way to filter for jobs that are based in Europe. When I try putting "Europe" in the "Where" field, I still get US- or Australia-based jobs. Is there a way to make a filter like this? I don't care about the country; I want to find any job across the entire European continent.

Comment: This might be seen as being too broad, [as per this q asking to be able to specify 'willing to relocate anywhere'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84042/for-careers-relocation-how-to-specify-anywhere)

Comment: I'd like to do just the country personally. I don't intend to move to the US, but I live close to the boarder so I get results from both NYC and Toronto all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a limitation of our geocoding system that large areas (continents, hemispheres) don’t work well. It’s shortcoming on our part. We’ll work on it.