# inputting EU, Europe or similar as a Career relocation is not possible

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Actually when inputting EU, Europe or similar as a Career relocation option, it is translated into "United States", which is rather amusing.

Should I input all the Schengen countries, incl./excl. Ireland & the UK to indicate that I really am interested in seeing what is available in not just one specific EU-country?

Comment: Why Schengen? Wouldn't EU / EEA make more sense?

Comment: For that matter I'd like to specify *"the English-speaking developed world"*, but I guess that isn't easy for the DB to interpret.

Comment: EU/EEA would make perfect sense. 'United States' does not :)

Comment: The [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) is different from EU; foe example, it includes Switzerland, which is not part of EU.

Comment: Probably related: [Can I filter jobs on Careers by continent?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123744/can-i-filter-jobs-on-careers-by-continent)

Comment: @nicklarsen This is status-completed, but while I can now input EU ("all eu countries") I still get the message telling me you need something more specific. It still seems to work, so perhaps the error message needs to be removed. Or maybe it needs to be reworded to an advice instead?

Comment: I would also like to be able to say "I am willing to relocate anywhere in the EU/EEA, and have the right to start work immediately anywhere in the EU/EEA"